# How to create a Kafka Connect connector at worker creation time?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Suppose I have a Kafka Connect worker that I built using Docker from the `confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect` image deploying to a server and spinning up a worker.  Now most of the time, the connector will already exist since I have created it using a REST API call to POST on port 8083.  But how would I create my connector (if it doesn't already exist) via a script at worker start time?  Can I somehow give my worker steps to run after it spins up?

Answer (score 2):

As cricket_007 says, you can embed it in the command with a call out to a mounted script, or you can just put it all inline, [like this example](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/build-a-streaming-pipeline/docker-compose.yml#L126-L149). If you do this note that in the command section, `$` are replaced with `$$` to avoid the error `Invalid interpolation format for "command" option`

```yaml
  kafka-connect-01:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.4.0
[…]
    command: 
      - bash 
      - -c 
      - |
[…]
        echo "Launching Kafka Connect worker"
        /etc/confluent/docker/run & 
        #
        echo "Waiting for Kafka Connect to start listening on localhost ⏳"
        while : ; do
          curl_status=$$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://localhost:8083/connectors)
          echo -e $$(date) " Kafka Connect listener HTTP state: " $$curl_status " (waiting for 200)"
          if [ $$curl_status -eq 200 ] ; then
            break
          fi
          sleep 5 
        done
        echo -e "\n--\n+> Creating Data Generator source"
        curl -s -X PUT -H  "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8083/connectors/source-datagen-01/config \
            -d '{
            "connector.class": "io.confluent.kafka.connect.datagen.DatagenConnector",
            "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
            "kafka.topic": "ratings",
            "max.interval":750,
            "quickstart": "ratings",
            "tasks.max": 1
        }'
        sleep infinity
```

Comment: I am not familiar with what this example file is.  At first I thought it was YAML, but it looks nothing like my YAML that helm generates.  I recognize the shell commands there, but clearly there is a big gap in my Docker/Kubernetes knowledge; can you point it out to me so I can go study up on it?

Comment: Ah sorry - yes this is a YAML extract from a [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) file. unfortunately, I don't know k8s/helm so I can't translate, but you basically need to take the [`command`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command) section and set it as the command for your Docker container when you run it.

Comment: @Pat The Confluent Helm Charts don't have command available for connect, only JMX exporter. Source https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/blob/master/charts/cp-kafka-connect/templates/deployment.yaml#L41

Answer (score 1):

It requires an overloaded `command`

Original issue: https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/issues/467

Solution

```
  volumes:
    - $PWD/scripts:/scripts  # TODO: Create this folder ahead of time, on your host
  command: 
    - bash 
    - -c 
    - |
      /etc/confluent/docker/run & 
      echo "Waiting for Kafka Connect to start listening on kafka-connect ⏳"
      while [ $$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://kafka-connect:8083/connectors) -eq 000 ] ; do 
        echo -e $$(date) " Kafka Connect listener HTTP state: " $$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://kafka-connect:8083/connectors) " (waiting for 200)"
        sleep 5 
      done
      nc -vz kafka-connect 8083
      echo -e "\n--\n+> Creating Kafka Connector(s)"
      /scripts/create-connectors.sh  # Note: This script is stored externally from container
      sleep infinity
```

Comment: Other solution would be start `connect-distributed` once, anywhere, configure the internal topics, post a connector (which saves to config topic), then start N containers, and they all pick up the same config

Comment: I am not familiar with what this example file is.  At first I thought it was YAML, but it looks nothing like my YAML that helm generates.  I recognize the shell commands there, but clearly there is a big gap in my Docker/Kubernetes knowledge; can you point it out to me so I can go study up on it?

Comment: It's yaml... It's docker compose because you never stated which way you're running the container. The Confluent Helm Charts should have a command section as well on a deployment

Answer (score 0):

If you use for automation such tools like [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/), this config may be useful:

```yaml
- hosts: kafka-connect-docker
  name: deploy kafka connect cluster
  become: yes
  gather_facts: yes
  serial: '{{ serial|default(1) }}'
  tasks:
    # it's not fully working example
    ...

    - name: run container
      notify: wait ports
      docker_container:
        name: kafka-connect
        image: "{{ docker_registry }}/kafka-connect:2.4.0-1.3.0"
        entrypoint: ["sh", "-c", "'exec /opt/kafka/bin/connect-distributed.sh /etc/kafka-connect/connect-distributed.properties >> /var/log/kafka-connect/stderrout.log 2>&1'"]
        restart_policy: always
        network_mode: host
        state: started

    - name: call wait ports
      command: /bin/true
      notify: wait ports

  handlers:
    - name: restart container
      shell: docker restart kafka-connect
      notify: wait ports

    - name: wait ports
      wait_for: port=10900 timeout=300 host=127.0.0.1
      changed_when: True
      notify: check cluster status

    - name: check cluster status
      uri: 
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:10900/connectors"
        status_code: 200
      register: cluster_status_json_response
      until: cluster_status_json_response.status == 200
      retries: 60
      delay: 5


- hosts: kafka-connect-docker[0]
  name: deploy connectors configs
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: restore connectors configs
      uri:
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:10900/connectors/{{ item }}/config"
        method: PUT
        return_content: yes
        body_format: json
        headers:
          Accept: "application/json"
          Content-Type: "application/json"
        body: "{{ lookup('template', 'roles/kafka-connect/templates/etc/kafka-connect/tasks/' + item + '.json') }}"
        status_code: 200, 201
        timeout: 60
      with_items: "{{ connector_configs }}"
```